# Why "failed to chmod "would happen?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

my code for copying sqlite database to assets folder is like this . but something went wrong . `private Context context;
        private String db_path;

```
/*public static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE " + 
            TABLE_NAME +"  ("+
    KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMATY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
    KEY_USERNAME+" INTEGER NOT NULL, "+
    KEY_PASSWORD+" VARCHAR NOT NULL, "+
    KEY_HOMEADDRESS+" VARCHAR, "+
    KEY_LICENSENO+" VARCHAR );";*/
```

My DbHelper class is

```
public DbHelper(Context context){
    super(context,"DATABASE_NAME",null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.DATABASE_NAME=DATABASE_NAME;
    this.context=context;
    db_path="/data/data/"+context.getPackageName()+"/databases/";
}

//create an empty database on the system to rewrite
public void crearDataBase() throws IOException{
    boolean dbExists=checkDataBase();
    if(dbExists){

    }else{
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try{
            copyDataBase();
        }catch(IOException e){
            throw new Error("Error copying databse");
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase(){
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB=null;
    try{
        String myPath=db_path+DATABASE_NAME;
        checkDB=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }catch(SQLiteException e){

    }
    if(checkDB!=null){
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB!=null?true:false;
}

//copy database from local asset-folder to the system folder
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
    //open local database as the input stream
    InputStream myInput=context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

    //path to the just created empty database
    String outFileName=db_path+DATABASE_NAME;

    //open the emoty database as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput=new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
    byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while((length=myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer,0,length);
    }
    //close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

/*public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
    //open the database
    String myPath=db_path+DATABASE_NAME;
    myDataBase=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY); 

}*/


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    //delete table
    db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);

    }`
```

and the log cat is like this :

```
05-08 04:24:31.644: D/dalvikvm(7015): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 124K, 6% free 3242K/3440K, paused 40ms, total 42ms
05-08 04:24:32.134: D/gralloc_goldfish(7015): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
05-08 04:25:42.644: I/Choreographer(7015): Skipped 62 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-08 04:25:45.244: W/FileUtils(7015): Failed to chmod(/data/data/com.example.login/databases/DATABASE_NAME): libcore.io.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

The application could work on the emulator, but not on the phone.
Also, my phone does not have a SD card, is that ok for an external sqlite database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why there is "failed to chmod" in logcat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537364/why-there-is-failed-to-chmod-in-logcat)

Answer (score 0):

1) in line

```
super(context,"DATABASE_NAME",null,DATABASE_VERSION);
```

i think should be

```
super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
```

2) Is it really value of DATABASE_NAME the same as db name from assets?

3) DATABASE_NAME should contain extension. Something like "mydb.db".

Comment: Yes, DATABASE_NAME is the name of the database under the assets. i export it from the file explorer and then edit it. And if there is an expansion, where should the "mydb.db" used.  If i do not have the SD card, what will the influence be ? Thank you.

Comment: 1) Write line where you initialize toy DATABASE_NAME. 2) You use internal storage, so doesn't matter if external exists.